# Problem when watching for pristine status of form in reactive angular form

Tags: angular, froala

I have enclosed a stackblitz example which demonstrates the editor in a reactive form. I register and subscribe to changes on the form. If the Form is initial loaded changing text in editor will fire of the change function. If you click on the save button this is no longer the case for small changes in the editor, if you hit enter or insert image it will fire. If i change the value in the sample input, it fires the change even after we hit save button. Not sure what causes this issue but it causes a problem when monitoring the form for changes. It seems that when you hit the enter button or insert image it will even after the submit trigger a pristine update, but if changing only 1 or 2 char on same line that's not the case. 
Does anyone have an idea what is causing this or is this a bug in the component ?

[StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-froala-v3-custombutton-dynamic-macatm)

Comment: In your Debug Form State button you should put `type="button"`. As it is now it triggers a form submit.

Comment: Sorry but the submit or button type have 0 impact on the issue

Comment: You are right but as it is now, clicking Debug Form State button executes `create(formData)` and disables the Save button. Just try it and you will see.

Comment: Thats not the reason, the Save is disabled as long as the form is prestine, the issue is that the editor does not trigger a prestine = false after you hit saved which resets the prestine to true

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the stackblitz example and notice that, you have the blur event on your editor options,

```
   blur : function() {
              // save selection so we can restore just before inserting any element
              // this.selection.save();
   },
```

when I commented the `this.selection.save()` everything works fine,

Can you avoid to using this function `this.selection.save()`?

Comment: No i need the blur Function. After some more testing i think this might be a bug in the froala editor and i opened ticket with them.